# Calculating standing times

Tags: analysis, trajectory

I have n objects and each object has m positions.

Every position is defined by x, y (in millimeters) and a (unix) timestamp.

```
{
  objId: 'a-b-c',
  x: 123,
  y: 567,
  date: 123456789,
}
```

Now I want to calculate how long an object *didn't* move.

My first algorithm always updated a list of "last" positions for every object if it got a different position. If the new position wasn't different, I increased the standing duration for that object.

Problem I encountered:

The system which tracs the objects (almost) never delivers the same coordinates even if the object didn't *physically* move.

```
x:123 -> x:120 -> x:124 -> x:123 -> ...
```

Should I just round to centimeters or decimenters or are there "standard" GIS-algorithms to solve this?

Answer (score 3):

I think *dwell time* and *trajectory* are more appropriate words for this.  See "[Estimating the most likely space–time paths, dwell times and path uncertainties from vehicle trajectory data: A time geographic method](https://u.osu.edu/miller.81/2015/09/09/estimating-the-most-likely-space-time-paths-dwell-times-and-path-uncertainties-from-vehicle-trajectory-data-a-time-geographic-method/)".

-- Tang J, Song Y, Miller HJ, Zhou X (2015)